# concavity of functions of many variables

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a function in many variables, the function is concave and non-increasing in each one of the variables, is the entire function concave?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x,y) = xy$ on $(-\infty,0)$. Then, $f$ is concave (in fact linear) and decreasing in each variable. However, the Hessian of $f$ is indefinite.